# PHP syntax highlighting in VIM

Tags: vim, macvim

When I enable syntax highlighting in vim, in PHP I get a red highlight on a semi-colon followed by a single or multiple line comment. I originally thought this was some conflict in vim, but my .vimrc only has `syntax enable` at this point and I still get the error.

ex://

```
<?php
require_once 'autoloader.php';

/* Initialize variables */
```

will display as:
[image: output]

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Does `require_once('autoloader.php');` work?

Comment: No, it still gets the same highlighting error. It seems like there's an overzealous regex somewhere, but I don't know where it could be. Nothing is in the vimrc except `syntax enable`.

Comment: What is interesting is it doesn't do it with `echo "Output";` as the first line and if it's doing it, it doesn't matter how many blank lines are in between.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue was with my copy of the php syntax file. I renamed ~/.vim/syntax/php.vim and things went back to normal.